# how to split the two content both equally in a3 sheet using jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

we having A3 page so i need separate the content in jasper report like

1
2
3
4
5
and remaining there is second column
6
7
8
9
10

but in my output displays like below order
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

so please let me know the exact answer.. Thank you

Comment: Could you add the full JRXML-file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change a property in the report.

The Column Count property divedes in columns for the Detail section in the report.

It can be filled vertically: first completes a column from top to bottom, and then moves to the right

Or horizontally: First completes a row from left to right, and then goes to the next row below.

[Where to find the property in TIBCO Jaspersoft Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8vWl.png)